# is there a function in python to convert this object in to integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

[image]

I am trying to convert column 'reward levels' to int type, it seems that it is listed as object type.

I have tried

**.astype(int)**

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '25,50,100,250,500,1,000,2,500'**

also:

**tuple(map(int, df['reward levels'].split(',')))**

**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'**

final:

**pd.to_numeric(df['reward levels'])

ValueError: Unable to parse string "25,50,100,250,500,1,000,2,500" at position 0**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By26wLpAqHfQaF9Jb19RUFVnNjA/view

link to the data. Thanks in advance I am a novice.

Comment: But it's not an `int`.  It's a series of `int`s, and they're not even all the same length.  What do you expect pandas to do with this?

Comment: Maybe `df['reward levels'].str.split()`?

Comment: or Maybe `df.explode('reward levels')`

Comment: can you post the actual data?  It will be difficult to determine if commas are meant as delimeters or number formatting in this `'25,50,100,250,500,1,000,2,500'`, if the last numbers are `1000` and `2500` for example

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as text, we can not copy the contents from image. You can do `df[:5].to_dict()` and add the output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your data, it seems that `reward levels` has either `,` separated values preceding with `$` sign or `NaN`, so what you can do is, for each value of `reward levels`:

1. Remove all `$` signs, you can simply replace them by empty string `''`
2. Split each values by comma `,`, you will get list of integers as list of string
3. Call `pd.to_numeric` for each row in `reward levels`

```py
df['reward levels'] = df['reward levels'].str.replace('$', '', regex=False).str.split(',').apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
1                                       [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]
2        [1, 10, 25, 40, 50, 100, 250, 1, 0, 1, 337, 9, 1]
3        [1, 10, 25, 30, 50, 75, 85, 100, 110, 250, 500...
4                              [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 250]
                               ...                        
45952                                        [20, 50, 100]
45953    [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 50, 75, 100, 200, 250, 500,...
45954                                   [10, 25, 100, 500]
45955                         [15, 16, 19, 29, 29, 39, 75]
45956    [25, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 1, 250, 2, 50...
Name: reward levels, Length: 45957, dtype: object
```

Furthermore, if you  wish to have each of the list items on a separate row, you can use `explode`

```py
df.explode('reward levels')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
0         25
0         50
0        100
0        250
0        500
        ... 
45956    250
45956      2
45956    500
45956      5
45956      0
Name: reward levels, Length: 416706, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want the output format to be.  If you just want to split the strings as comma separated values and cast them as ints, you can use:

```
data = {'reward_levels': {0: '25,50,100,250,500,1,000,2,500',
  1: '25,50,10',
  2: '15,16,19,22'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.apply(lambda x: [int(j) for j in x.reward_levels.split(",")], axis=1)
```

but the result may not be exactly what you want:

```
0    [25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1, 0, 2, 500]
1                             [25, 50, 10]
2                         [15, 16, 19, 22]
```

It is more typical to have a single value for each cell/index.  You can either explode into multiple columns, or duplicate as rows; the latter might be preferable as your arrays are of unequal length:

```
df.reward_levels.str.split(",", expand=True)
```

output:

```
    0   1    2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0  25  50  100   250   500     1   000     2   500
1  25  50   10  None  None  None  None  None  None
2  15  16   19    22  None  None  None  None  None
```

or

```
df.reward_levels.str.split(",").explode().astype(int)
```

output:

```
0     25
0     50
0    100
0    250
0    500
0      1
0      0
0      2
0    500
1     25
1     50
1     10
2     15
2     16
2     19
2     22
```